# Getting the list name from url with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to parse any given SharePoint URL and get back the site, web and list references using the code below. I would like to achieve this even if I provide the URL of an item. The code below works if i provide the URL of the list/library. If i provide the URL of an item in a list/library it throws an exception but also appears to work.

I do not understand why I am getting an exception when using an Item URL. What else do i need to do to make this work for any URL?

Code -

```
$listURL = "http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
$listURLWithItem= "http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST/Shared%20Documents/Test2.docx"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($listURL)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl($listURL)

"Output with list url-"
$site.url
$web.url
$list.Title

"Output when using item url-"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($listURLWithItem)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl($listURLWithItem)
$site.url
$web.url
$list.Title
```

The resulting output - with the second instance generating an exception

```
Output with list url-
http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST
http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST
Shared Documents

Output when using item url-
Exception calling "GetListFromWebPartPageUrl" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot complete this action.

Please try again."
At line:15 char:39
+ $list = $web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl <<<< ($listURLWithItem)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST
http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST
Shared Documents
```

Comment: After exception you are getting correct result?

Comment: The reason you are getting the correct value is because the list object is still holding the value from the previous computation. The second part where you are trying get list name with item url has not got evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below script. I have tried to get the listitem object out of the url.
A check is necessary if your Urls contain relative urls as well.

```
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($listURL)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$listitem=$web.GetListItem($listURL);
"Output with list url-"
$site.url
$web.url
$listitem.ParentList.Title

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($listURLWithItem)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$listitem=$web.GetListItem($listURLWithItem);
"Output with list url-"
$site.url
$web.url
$listitem.ParentList.Title
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to check the URL and then call the appropriate method. Below is the script I finally put together and it is working for me so far.

```
if( $listURL.ToLower().Contains( "AllItems.aspx".ToLower() ) -or $listURL.ToLower().Contains( "DispForm.aspx".ToLower() ) )
{
    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($listURL)
    $web = $site.OpenWeb()

    $list=$web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl($listURL);
    "Output with list url-"
    $site.url
    $web.url
    $list.Title
}
else
{
    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($listURL)
    $web = $site.OpenWeb()

    # Use GetListItem when URL contains list item, example - http://portal.contoso.com/Shared%20Documents/test.docx
    $listItem=$web.GetListItem($listURL);
    "Output with list item url-"
    $site.url
    $web.url
    $listItem.ParentList.Title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page url you must provide is the url to the webpart page. The url you provide is the url to de actual document.

For example an url like

```
http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST/Shared%20Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

should work.

> SPList GetListFromWebPartPageUrl(string pageUrl)
>
> pageUrlType: System.String 
>  
>   A string that contains the site-relative URL of a Web Part page, for example,
>   /Lists/Announcements/AllItems.aspx.

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistfromwebpartpageurl%28v=office.14%29.Aspx) for more information

Comment: The input URL should ideally be that of the list or library however i am trying to make it more generic. It seems i have to write some more logic to parse the URL to accept any URL. I do get a correct result even after the exception. 
`try{$list = $web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl($listURLWithItem)}
catch{"Unable to get list."}
$site.url
$web.url
$list.Title`